# How to update all references in ebean orm

Tags: java, orm, mapping, ebean

I am having a problem where i am updating a model in ebean, but other references to the model are not being changed.
I was wondering whether or not it is possible to automatically update or refresh any models that reference the updated model using joined columns or @ManyToMany mappings.

This is my test code:

```
// Create students and club
Student john = new Student("John");
Student lizz = new Student("Lizz");
Club soccer = new Club("Soccer");

// Save the students
server.save(john);
server.save(lizz);

// Add them to their club
john.getClubs().add(soccer);
server.save(john);
lizz.getClubs().add(soccer);
server.save(lizz);

// Reload users (fresh)
john = server.find(Student.class).where().ieq("name", "john").findUnique();
lizz = server.find(Student.class).where().ieq("name", "lizz").findUnique();
System.out.println("Club: " + lizz.getClubs().get(0).getName());

// Modify the club name
john.getClubs().get(0).setName("Baseball");
System.out.println("Club: " + lizz.getClubs().get(0).getName());

// Update the club
server.save(john);
System.out.println("Club: " + lizz.getClubs().get(0).getName());
```

and these are my models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Club> clubs;

    @Version
    private long version;
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clubs")
public class Club {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn
    private List<Student> students;

    @Version
    private long version;
}
```

The output is that club remains as Soccer, like so:
Club: Soccer
Club: Soccer
Club: Soccer

Comment: When the code reloads john and lizz ... as there is no spanning transaction / persistence context ... this creates 2 independent object graphs.  Those object graphs represent a "snapshot of part of the database at a point in time and at a certain isolation level (read committed by default as per JPA spec etc).

Comment: @RobBygrave that makes sense, i set the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE because it supports both SQLite and MySQL, some others don't
Is it possible to keep the same reference at all times?

Comment: At SERIALIZABLE Optimistic concurrency checking doesn't work (well, the check is relative to the start of the transaction).  In general you need to start using pessimistic locking at SERIALIZABLE.  For an application with high concurrency that is a problem.  So READ_COMMITTED is IMO a much much much better choice. Unless ...

Comment: ... unless you are on a mobile device etc. On mobile you could look at https://realm.io ... as an alternative to SQLite (and not use an ORM).

Comment: "Is it possible to keep the same reference at all times?" ... at high concurrency it is not (not for an ORM and not for the database either).  If you are using an MVCC database then it doesn't have a single reference to a logical row but instead can have many (versions of that row and  based on transaction isolation levels and transaction start time you get the appropriate version of that row). In my view MVCC architecture is now the most dominant for high concurrency applications (readers don't block writers, writers don't block readers) ...

Comment: ... with DB2 on mainframe being the big popular locking based database (the very successful non MVCC database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying John but printing Lizz.  Lizz hasn't changed (in that the club for Lizz has been loaded and it is not refreshed).

The reason is because the fetch of John and Lizz are in 2 different transactions and as such have 2 different persistence contexts.

If there was a transaction spanning the fetch of BOTH John and Lizz then the Club would have been the  same/single instance for both as the underlying persistence context is scoped to the transaction and ensures they use the same instance for the Club.

As a side point you should look at turning on SQL and Transaction logging such that you confirm it does what you think it should:

```
<!-- LOGBACK configuration -->

<!-- SQL and bind values -->
<logger name="org.avaje.ebean.SQL" level="TRACE"/>

<!-- Transaction Commit and Rollback events -->
<logger name="org.avaje.ebean.TXN" level="TRACE"/>
```

For logging configuration refer to http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/setup/logging

Do:

```
server.beginTransaction();
try {
   // persistence context scoped to transaction so 
   // .. now spans both fetches giving John and Lizz
   // .. the same shared Club instance
   john = server.find(Student.class).where().ieq("name", "john").findUnique();
  lizz = server.find(Student.class).where().ieq("name", "lizz").findUnique();
} finally {
  server.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: thank you this is very helpful.
However, in practice i would not load them both at the same time.
But i would like to change the club for one student without having all the clubs be inconsistent.

Comment: Refer to the other discussion above.

Comment: FYI: There is a video discussing Ebean's "Persistence Context" at https://youtu.be/Y18HsBkeLuk  ... comparing it to JPA and hopefully explaining a bit more why this works like this.